Local and remote push notification (using FCM) for Android/iOS React-Native Expo app
I'm developing a React-Native android/iOS app using Expo. At this moment I need to implement both local and remote push notification (using FCM for both app) but it's quite complicated to understand if exists a tool that fit with my needs and how to setup the whole environment (I have already a server that sends message to FCM using Firebase token [that I need to gather from apps] to trigger notifications).
I already tried Notifee and Expo Notifications, but I didn't get them work completely.
Waiting for your suggestions and help
Thanks in advance!
